# Stripe - PaymentIntent is null when I create or update a subscription

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm new to Stripe, so if I'm missing something, please advise.

Tech Stack:
React (front-end)
Node (back-end)

I am trying to create or update a Stripe subscription, and in either case, I get a null paymentIntent. I thought I read that I should check the paymentIntent status to make sure the payment for the subscription has gone through.

My subscription workflow, when a user signs up, I create a Stripe customer and add them to a subscription. This subscription is a free tier so no payment method is needed. The `payment_intent` is null.

```
//create a Stripe customer code here
...

//create the subscription 
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{ priceID }],
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
});

const invoice = subscription.latest_invoice as Stripe.Invoice;
const payment_intent = invoice.payment_intent as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
```

Later after they want to upgrade to a paid plan, I request a credit card and upgrade their current subscription to a paid plan. On the front-end, I use Stripe Element and create a payment method by doing this.

```
if (!elements || !stripe) {
     return 
}

const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

if (!cardElement) {
     return
}

// Confirm Card Setup
const { 
     error, 
     paymentMethod 
} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
     type: 'card',
     card: cardElement,
     billing_details:{
          name,
          email: currentUser.email,
          phone,
          address: {
               city,
               line1: address,
               state,
          },
     }
});

if (error) {
     console.log("createPaymentMethod: ", error.message)
} else {
     const paymentMethodId = paymentMethod!.id
     // Switch to new subscription
     await switchSubscription(priceID, paymentMethodId)
}
```

And on the back-end, I get the stripe customer, add a payment method, and upgrade the subscription to the new plan.  The `payment_intent` is null.

```
function switchSubscription(priceID, user, paymentMethod) {
     //get Stripe customer code here ...
     ...

     await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(paymentMethod, { customer: customer.id });
     await stripe.customers.update(customer.id, {
        invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: paymentMethod },
    });

    const currentSubscription = await getSubscriptions(user)

     const updatedSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
          currentSubscription.id,
     {
          cancel_at_period_end: false,
          proration_behavior: 'always_invoice',
          items: [
               {
                    id: currentSubscription.items.data[0].id,
                    price: priceID,
               },
          ],
          expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
     })

     const invoice = updatedSubscription.latest_invoice as Stripe.Invoice;
     const payment_intent = invoice.payment_intent as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
}
```

Comment: Does the `updatedSubcription.latest_invoice` have the other properties present, or is the invoice itself not present? If it is present, make sure that the amount is greater than zero (otherwise there won't be a payment intent present).

Comment: @taintedzodiac, The documentation says to check the status of the paymentIntent but for the first subscription, the price is 0.00 (it's the free tier) what status should I be checking to make sure everything was setup properly in that use case? I want to make sure the subscription was created and invoiced because on that date every month they will get charged either 0.00 or greater depending on their plan.

Comment: @taintedzodiac I checked the invoice and all other values are there, just payment Intent is null. `updatedSubcription.latest_invoice.total` is  14900, so there should be a payment Intent

Comment: Facing same issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? facing the same.

Comment: Same here ... any solution?

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Have no Idea what to do

Comment: same here.. any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this probleme by adding the quantity to items. I think the invoice is not created (null) when the total amount is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your customer might have a balance in their account so that the amount might be taken out from the customer's available balance. I think for cases like that, Stripe doesn't create a payment intent, and therefore returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

For Subscriptions that are created with free trial or amount $0 to $0.5, for that stripe won't generate a payment intent. In order to solve this issue you need to set "payment_behavior: default_incomplete" while creating the subscription with free trial or the first Invoice is $0 then you will be getting back a Setup Intent at pending_setup_intent. [check the stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents). Then you get the setupIntent_clientSecret and sent it to your client to complete the payment process by using stripe.confirmCardSetup().[stripe reference](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup)

Here is the code example for all this process. starting from client

first you create a payment method by

```
 const createPaymentMethodResult = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: "card",
  card: elements.getElement(
    CardNumberElement,
    CardExpiryElement,
    CardCvcElement
  ),
  billing_details: billing_details,
  metadata,
});
```

then get the paymentMethodId from

```
//! getting paymentMethod ID
const paymentMethodID = createPaymentMethodResult?.paymentMethod?.id;
```

now make a request to your backend to send the paymentMethod Id because we will use payment Method Id while creating a customer and attach it to that customer and set it their default payment method

```
//! Now make request to backend for creating subscription

  const url = "http://localhost:3001/subscription/create";
  const res = await axios.post(url, {
    payment_method_id: paymentMethodID,
    email: userData?.email,
    selectedProduct: {
      productName: selectedProduct?.productName,
      productPriceId: selectedProduct?.productPriceId,
    },
    billing_details,
    metadata,
  });
  
  // getting the client_secret in response from server
  const { pending_setup_intent: client_secret, success } = res?.data;

  //! Now confirm CardPayment if using trial period
  const confirmedCardPaymentResult = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
    client_secret,
    {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(
          CardNumberElement,
          CardExpiryElement,
          CardCvcElement
        ),
        billing_details,
      },
    }
  );
```

Now for the backend server code

```
 // getting the data from the request 
 const { email, payment_method_id, selectedProduct, billing_details,
 metadata } = req.body;
 const { productName, productPriceId } = selectedProduct;
```

Now creating the customer with the paymentMethodId

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  payment_method: payment_method_id,
  email: email,
  invoice_settings: {
    default_payment_method: payment_method_id,
  },
  metadata,
});
```

creating trial period for this example it's 7 days

```
const date = moment().valueOf();
const trial = moment(date).add(7, "days").valueOf();
const unixTrial = moment(trial).unix();
```

now creating the actual subscription

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: customer.id,
  items: [{ price: productPriceId }],
  expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
  description: productName,
  trial_end: unixTrial,
  payment_behavior:"default_incomplete" //! add this if using trial
  metadata,
});
```

now getting setup intent

```
//! getting setup intent from sub to extract the client secret, if using 
  trial with subscription
  const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.retrieve(
  subscription?.pending_setup_intent
);
```

after this getting setupIntent client secret

```
     //! getting client secret from setup-intet
     const pending_setup_intent = setupIntent?.client_secret,
```

now sending the response back to client so the client can use this setupIntent client secret to confirm card setup or payment

```
res.json({
  customerId: customer.id,
  subscriptionId: subscription.id,
  success: true,
  pending_setup_intent: pending_setup_intent, 
});
```

Comment: hey ateeb, will this ensure that the user enters the card info and only then we create the subscription for the user because I see on my code that when I create the subscription for free trial or 0$ the user is just "subscribed" without the billing details, because my code has the logic to create the user without getting the billings details and generate the stripe Id client secret first

Comment: well you need to make sure to get the billing or card info before creating a customer or subscription. You need to get the card info in front end and then from the card you need to create a payment method then you will get a payment method i'd that needs to be sent to your server and then you will create a customer and subscription with free trial and then you need to get the client secret back to client and then you need to confirm card payment and then your setup will be completed.

Comment: or if you create a customer with the payment method i'd and save it as the customer's default payment method then it'll make sure that your customer has the billing details because you create subscription on a customer, so setting up a customer before creating a subscription will make sure that your customer has a payment method and billing info because on the client you first check for the user's card info and then try to create a payment method (api reference https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create) so if it's a success then you continue the process on server.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix if you're creating a subscription *with* a **free trial** ...

... `client_secret` will be in `pending_setup_intent` because of the trial .. not where you'd expect to find it in `latest_invoice.payment_intent`

So:

```
// you probably have this already
'payment_behavior' => 'default_incomplete',
// and you're expanding some stuff already (from the docs)
'expand' => [
    // and this, expecting the payment intent
    'latest_invoice.payment_intent',
    // but for a trial, expand *this* element `client_secret` etc..
    'pending_setup_intent',
],
```